# Sorting table by project

Tags: vue.js

I have an object that looks like this

```
projects: Object
    Admin: Object
        Project 1: Array[1]
            0: Object
                name: Admin Project 1
                description: Admin Project 1 Description
        Project 2: Array[2]
            0: Object
                name: Admin Project 2 part 1
                description: Admin Project 2 part 1 Description
            1: Object
                name: Admin Project 2 part 2
                description: Admin Project 2 part 2 Description
```

And what I'm trying to do is to display this information on a table.
The issue I'm having is that because of the way I'm creating the table I'm not able to group them by their sub category (EG: Project 2).

So my table would look like this.

[Codepen of how I want it to look like](https://codepen.io/ifrit478/pen/yLpKxxO?editors=1000)

This is how it is looking like at the moment.

[Codepen of the wrong way the table looks like](https://codepen.io/ifrit478/pen/mdpxGxz)

Here is my code

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm" style="width: 100%" v-for="(value, key) in projects">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="font-size: 90%; background: #a0a0a0; color: #fafafa; font-weight: normal">
            <th colspan="8" style="text-indent: 8px;">{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-size: 90%; background: #d0d0d0; color: #606060;" v-for="(v, k) in value">
            <th colspan="7" style="text-indent: 32px;">{{ k }}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(p, kk) in value">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr  v-for="vp in p">
                        <td>{{ vp.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ vp.description }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I did not understand as you already have working sample. Then, why you want to do that again ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal the working example is hard coded

Comment: @moritzgvt Sorry i missed that. I added an answer. Hope this will work!

Answer (score 1):

The `tbody` elements are structurize themselves below each other (see [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table))

If you add the contents of the projects inside the same `tbody` element as additional rows it should work:

```html
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" style="width: 100%" v-for="(value, key) in projects">
    <thead>
      <tr style="font-size: 90%; background: #a0a0a0; color: #fafafa; font-weight: normal">
        <th colspan="8" style="text-indent: 8px;">{{key}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody v-for="(v, k) in value">
      <tr style="font-size: 90%; background: #d0d0d0; color: #606060;">
        <th colspan="7" style="text-indent: 32px;">{{ k }}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="vp in v">
        <td>{{ vp.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ vp.description }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

EDIT: I update the code to use multiple `tbody` elements and a `thead` for the object root – should be semantically more correct I think.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because all your for loop have to be imbricated inside parent divs

Here is a much simpler example using only `div`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    projects: {
        Admin: {
        'Project 1': [
          {name: 'Admin Project 1', description: 'Admin Project 1 Description'}
        ],
        'Project 2': [
          {name: 'Admin Project 2 part 1', description: 'Admin Project 2 part 1 Description'},
          {name: 'Admin Project 2 part 2', description: 'Admin Project 2 part 2 Description'}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, key) in projects">
    {{key}}
    
    <div v-for="(value2, key2) in value">
      {{key2}}
      
      <div v-for="(value3) in value2">
         {{value3.name}} - {{value3.description}}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in your case you have to think to another model of data.

Answer (score 0):

**Observations :**

- You forget to add `:key` attribute for each iteration. That is a good practice and helps in rendering the DOM.
- You added one extra iteration in your code which causes the issue in displaying the table properly.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    projects: {
        Admin: {
        'Project 1': [
          {name: 'Admin Project 1', description: 'Admin Project 1 Description'}
        ],
        'Project 2': [
          {name: 'Admin Project 2 part 1', description: 'Admin Project 2 part 1 Description'},
          {name: 'Admin Project 2 part 2', description: 'Admin Project 2 part 2 Description'}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" style="width: 100%" v-for="(value, key) in projects" :key="key">
    <thead>
      <tr style="font-size: 90%; background: #a0a0a0; color: #fafafa; font-weight: normal">
        <th colspan="8" style="text-indent: 8px;">{{key}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody v-for="(v, i) in Object.keys(value)" :key="i">
      <tr style="font-size: 90%; background: #d0d0d0; color: #606060;">
        <th colspan="7" style="text-indent: 32px;">{{ v }}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(p, ii) in value[v]" :key="ii">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ p.description }}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```